# Clearing a Vector space

Tags: c++

Hi people a quick question:

I have set a vector to a certain size, What i want to do is to empty that vector once it Hits the maximum space.

I have this Code for this:

```
vector<Point> Rightarm(20); 
    vector<Point> Leftarm(20);

    vector<Point>::const_iterator RightIter;
    vector<Point>::const_iterator LeftIter;

Rightarm.push_back(center);
    Leftarm.push_back(center1); 

    for(RightIter = Rightarm.begin(); RightIter != Rightarm.end(); ++RightIter)
    {
        circle(drawing, *RightIter, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), CV_FILLED); 
    }

    if(RightIter == Rightarm.end())
        {
            Rightarm.clear();
        }

    for(LeftIter = Leftarm.begin(); LeftIter != Leftarm.end(); ++LeftIter)
    {
        circle(drawing, *LeftIter, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), CV_FILLED);

    }

        if(LeftIter == Leftarm.end())
        {
            Leftarm.clear();
        }
```

The issue I have with this code is that the vector gets cleared every time...Where I want it to be emptied only after it hits the size limit of 20....

Can anyone spot where am going wrong with this...?

Comment: First, *which vector*? You have two. Second, both `Rightarm` and `Leftarm` will *always* clear with the code you have here. The termination of the for-loops above them guarantees that. Look at the continuance condition of each for-loop. Now look at the if-condition below each that clears the respective vectors. Hmmm....

Comment: 3 vectors there are only 2 Rightarm and Leftarm and 2 iterators...And thats the issue i am having that it always clears where i want the vectors to be emptied out only if they reach the maximum capacity which is 20

Comment: You just *set* the *size* to 20. Therefore are 20 objects in each their state based on your default-construction of a `Point`. You're then iterating through each, stopping when you reach the end, and clearing if you .. reached the end. Perhaps using capcity() and checking `size()` would work better.

Comment: The size is originally set to 20, then the `push_back()` calls will increase the size (by one for each vector each time this is called.

Comment: my vector stores a center positions of arms and as the arm moves from frame to frame a circle is drown to track the movements. SO the drawn dots stay on the image even if I empty the vector and Thats why I though it was wrong but it actually works :D After changing my if statment to `if(Rightarm.size() == 20)
  {
   Rightarm.clear();
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vector is always cleared because Leftarm.end() always points to the end of Leftarm. If Leftarm has 6 elements, then LeftIter points to the end of 6th element. Hence, in your code Leftarm vector will be always cleared. Change your code including that part with this:

```
if(Leftarm.size()==20) //or >=20
{
    Leftarm.clear();
}
```

Comment: I have tried this dosent work i get a Warning at (==) the compailer states this : Error: no operator "==" matches these operands. Thx for your answer dough

Comment: Actually your answer is correct......The reason why I though it was wrong when I initial tried it is because my vector stores a center positions of arms and as the arm moves a circle is drown to track the movements. SO the drawn dots stay on the image even if I empty the vector and Thats why I though it was wrong but it actually works :D

Comment: are you sure you typed it correctly? (`size` not `end`)